# How to package all dependencies for yum package?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

I need to install a YUM package(OpenNMS) on a server that doesn't have internet access. Is there a clean way to download all dependencies on a server with internet, package it , export it and install it on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes/no: there are some limited tools available, and a few problems.

On your server, you can use yumdownloader (or a [Downloadonly plugin for yum](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154) of yum) to create a local repository of packages. With either approach, you would download the package along with its dependencies.

This process is mentioned in

- [Download all dependencies with yumdownloader, even if already installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed).
- [yumdownloader vs repotrack](https://serverfault.com/questions/470964/yumdownloader-vs-repotrack)

There is a caveat: my experience is that the tools can be confused by the presence of existing packages on your server (i.e., installed) and will often overlook those in the actual download.  One way to work around this is to reprocess the list of downloaded files (asking for *their* dependencies) to check if no further files will be downloaded.

Of course, if successful, you will end up with a large number of packages (including glibc).  However the alternative would be to use the dependencies known to `rpm -qpR`, which require a lot of work to be useful.